# Configure the commit dialog in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

We have our Tasks maintained in JIRA.
If somebody has completed his Task and commits the changed documents, we want to have a second text besides the commit-Message-box. The second box should be used, that you can enter the name of the task you worked on -for easier tracking.
Is there any way to add a second text-box to the commit dialog, or does anyone know a good workaround?
I wanted to add a picture to make it easier to understand, but unfortunally i don't have enaugh reputation yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Read ["Integration with Bug Tracking Systems / Issue Trackers"](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html) from TSVN's docs
- Select, install, configure Jira-plugin (from two possible [in list](http://tortoisesvn.net/issuetrackerplugins.html))
- After all, you'll get [good interface](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/images/IssueTrackerQuery.png) for selecting issues in commit-dialogue

Comment: That is what I was searching for. I'm ashamned that i couldn't find it myself, even though I felt i have checked all TSVN docs.